# npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node attribution.js

Tags: node-modules

After running npm install I get this error, but I do not understand why.
Node is installed on my computer.

I was expecting my nodemodules folder to reinstall after deleting it.